# 11 | abba, where a and b are the digits in a 4 digit number.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Truly lost here, I know abba could look anything like 1221 or even 9999. However how do I prove 11 divides all of the possiblities?

Answer (score 5):

The number whose digits are $abba$ is really the number $a (1000) + b(100) + b(10) + a$, whihc you can write as $a(1001) + b(110) = a(11)(91) + b(11)(10)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help John. How did you know to multiply (1000),(100),(10),(1) to the variables?

Comment: @Bygonaut Those multiplications are just the definition of what base-10 positional notation means.

Comment: @Bygonaut Positional system: $1234$ means $1\cdot 1000+2\cdot100+3\cdot10+4$

Answer (score 1):

Also we have a general result. A number is divisible by 11 iff the sum of the digits in odd position less the sum of the digits in even position is a 11 multiple.

Here $(a+b)-(b+a)=0=0\cdot 11$